# how to set Owl Carousel to Autoplay

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html) jquery plugin. I want to use `autoplay`. but it doesn't work :

```
    <script src="{{base_url()}}assests/new/js/owl-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="{{base_url()}}assests/new/js/owl.autoplay.js"></script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items:1,
                loop:true,
                autoplay:true,
                autoplayTimeout:1000,
                autoplayHoverPause:true
            });
        });
```

my slider :

```
                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-slider m20" id="owl-carousel-slider" data-inner-pagination="true" data-white-pagination="true" data-nav="false" data-autoPlay="true">




                        <div>
                            <div onclick="goToProduct('home-kitchen');" class="bg-holder cursor-pointer">
                                <img src="{{base_url().'assests/new/img/sliders/home-kitchen.jpg'}}" />
                                <div class="bg-mask display-none"></div>
                                <div class="bg-front vert-center text-white text-center">
                                    <h2 class="text-uc"></h2>
                                    <p class="text-bigger"></p>
                                    <p class="text-hero"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <div onclick="goToProduct('digital-accessories');" class="bg-holder">
                                <img src="{{base_url().'assests/new/img/sliders/digital-accessories.jpg'}}"  />
                                <div class="bg-mask display-none"></div>
                                <div class="bg-front vert-center text-white text-center">
                                    <h2 class="text-uc"></h2>
                                    <p class="text-bigger"></p>
                                    <p class="text-hero"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

my website:

http://www.shadyab.com/category/tehran/commodity/all

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code instead:

```
owl = $(".owl-carousel");
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplaySpeed:1000,
    items:5,
    autoplay:true
});
```

it works with [owl-carousel](/questions/tagged/owl-carousel) version **2.2.1**

I think what might be a possible problem, as it happened to me, is using the `autoplayTimeout`.

When I included it in the above code, it only did the first sliding and stopped. But when I removed it, it started looping the `autoplay` infinitely as desired.

Hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `items:1` if you want to use autoplay.